# Dynamically add/delete textboxes and post to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Could I please get a skeleton of adding/removing dynamic textboxes and then posting the appended results.

I'd like it to look like this:

> [Empty Textbox][Add button]

once Value1 is put into the textbox and add is clicked it'll show:

> [Empty Textbox][Add button] 
>   [Value1][Remove button]

Once everything is added I want it to be posted and allow for people to remove any of the added textboxes.

I've been looking for examples and could not find one that works this way.

```
<form method="post" id="multi" action="process.php">

   <label for="cname">Company Name: <span class="required">*</span></label>
   <input type="text" size="30px" id="cname" name="cname" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['cname'] : '' ?>" placeholder="The Rainbow Kingdom" required autofocus />

   <label for="name">Contact Name: <span class="required">*</span></label>
   <input type="text" size="30px"id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['name'] : '' ?>" placeholder="John Doe" required autofocus />

   <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="required">*</span></label>
   <input type="email" size="50px" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['email'] : '' ?>" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" required />

   <label for="telephone">Telephone: </label>                   
   <input size="9px" placeholder="1112223333" autofocus maxlength="9" type="tel" id="telephone" name="telephone" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['telephone'] : '' ?>" />         
   <div>
      <label>Tag</label><input class="tag" type="text" name="" type="text" />
      <div id="content" ></div>
   </div>

   <label for="message">Message: <span class="required">*</span></label>
   <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message must be greater than 20 characters" required data-minlength="20"><?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['message'] : '' ?></textarea>

   <p id="req-field-desc">
      <span class="required">*</span> indicates a required field
   </p>
   <span id="loading"></span>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit!" id="submit-button" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can take a look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/MJUzM/). Pretty ugly but still readable. Enough for giving you the idea.
The value will be display as normal text, and will be stored in a hidden field with array-like name.
When you submit the form, the data from the hidden fields will be collected.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to put the button code within the form? It seems to not work when I do. Just for placement. Currently my form has more fields and i'd like for it to be placed in the middle of the form.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MJUzM/2/ If you place the button inside your form. You have to use <input type="button" /> or return false in the click handler.

Comment: Did you mena something like this? <input type="text" id="name" />
  <input type="button" id="Add" value="Add"/>
  <div id="list">
  </div>

Comment: I put return false; at the end of the js function. Each time i input something and click add it doesn't show in the list. http://eurothermwindows.com/ed/inputform.php

Comment: It works fine in the fiddle now http://jsfiddle.net/MJUzM/5/ but not on the website. Odd...

Comment: Could it have something to do with my form?             <form method="post" id="multi" action="process.php"> It still doesn't work even though it's a complete mirror.

Comment: there's already an <input id="name" type="text" autofocus="" required="" placeholder="John Doe" value="" name="name" size="30px"> in your form.

Comment: One last question for you. When the form gets submitted does the 'list' get posted automatically?

Comment: if you name an input, it will be submitted with the form automatically; you name it "something[]", on the server-side you'll get an array; and if you don't want it to be submitted, just don't name it

Comment: Thanks. So changing the name to name[] will post each of the textboxes values that are added by the user.

Comment: Seems like you already do that here:        $(hidden).attr({
           'type': 'hidden',
           'name': 'name[]',
           'value': name
       });

So basically the name[] array should be posted?

Comment: Got it thanks. $_POST['name'][0];

Comment: Is it possible to make your code use a multidimensional array to store more than 1 textbox per name. For example, four textboxes stored as name[0][0], name[0][1], name[0][2]. I've been looking over the code and can't seem to find out how it's been incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Go here:
http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/jquery-dynamically-adding-form-elements/

Comment: Shouldn't the `name` attribute have a value as an array, like `name='email[]'` instead of `name='email'`?

Comment: Thanks but this only removes the last one. I'd like a remove next to each of them. I'll og with this for now. How would i make it post the textboxes that have data in it?

Comment: GO and test this out: http://jsfiddle.net/xfYdP/ -- Just check it out. Did that in a hurry. But you should be able to tweak it to your needs. Cheers!